# Solr Suggester only adding first value from multivalued fields to suggest dictionary

Tags: solr

I'm using the Solr Suggest component to return suggestions for a field which is stored multivalued.
Problem: Only the first entry of this multivalued field for documents is added to the dictionary database.

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">suggestSkill</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.jaspell.JaspellLookupFactory</str>      <!-- org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst -->
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>     <!-- org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.HighFrequencyDictionaryFactory --> 
      <str name="field">skills</str>
      <str name="weightField">skills</str>
      <str name="storeDir">/usr/share/solr/live/solr/collection1/suggest/</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>

  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
     <str name="suggest.dictionary">suggestSkill</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Imagine the following documents:

```
 "docs": [
      {
        "id": "100444001",
        "firstName": "Piet",
        "lastName": "Huysentruyt",
        "skills": [
          "mongoDB",
          "angularJS",
          "Java ServerPages",
          "mongoDB",
          "angularRD"
        ],
        "_version_": 1482216060554838000
      },
      {
        "id": "104444",
        "firstName": "Bomas",
        "lastName": "Banciaux",
        "skills": [
          "bower",
          "Front-End Engineering"
        ],
        "_version_": 1482216060556935200
      }]
```

when searching for skill suggestions, only bower and mongo are available in the /suggest field. Even after suggest.build command. Any thoughts?

**Update: As of version 5 of Solr, the Suggester now works for multivalued fields**

Comment: Have you got your solution? I need to use the same thing.

Comment: In the end I did not use the solr Suggester as I did not find a way around this limitation. Instead I query for the 'skills' value field (and only return that field) with highlighting enabled; and remove any duplicate values in my service.

Comment: If upgrade to version 5 is not an option, probably have to use copyField to copy all values to another field to be used for suggestion.